# typescript functional clean architecture

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, f#, clean-architecture

I am working on gaining a deeper understanding of clean architecture from a functional programming point of view.  After reading several articles on the subject and most of the book, "Domain modeling made functional", the source is in f# but it really does a good job laying out the workflow and pipeline concepts.  I am, however, confused on how the dependency direction would be maintained through types vs interfaces.  For the OOP examples, they are using interfaces which makes sense for the inward nature of the dependencies.  For functional scenarios, I seem to be missing how this would be achieved, unless I were to create the types for the entities, etc. in the domain layer while adding types for the usecase functions and implement them in the Application layer, for example.  **I am trying to understand how to maintain the layering of clean architecture without compromising the core tenants of functional programming or if this is possible?**  For example, if I use the type analogy I listed above would this be the correct way to implement this as opposed to having the types and the behavior in the same folder in the same layer?  I haven't been able to find an example that ties together the Application, Domain, Infrastrucure, etc. together from a functional perspective.

Here is the github link for the Domain Modeling Made Functional example: https://github.com/swlaschin/DmmfWorkshop

Here is the link for the for a sample e-commerce application written in f#:  https://github.com/odytrice/Dumia

Here are two examples utilizing a c# oop approach, though I did not see the application folder used here:
https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb
https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject

Comment: I've written quite extensively on that topic. One place to start might be https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection, and then follow links to other articles. Feel free to write or comment if you have questions.

Comment: We have followed Mark's advice to good effect. I would point you to these two videos: https://youtu.be/cxs7oLGrxQ4 and https://youtu.be/US8QG9I1XW0 .

Comment: I'm not sure I can see where the compromise is? FP has (OOish) DI idiomatically from the ground up, its just higher order functions (HOF if u need a TLA), mark seemanns article explains it well for an OOPer.

Comment: Thank you.  Your series of articles are great.